# Access Violation when trying to bind Vertex Object Array

Tags: c++, opengl

I've just started digging into OpenGL and I've run into a problem trying to set a VOA.

It's giving me a run-time error of :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
```

At

```
    // Create and bind a VAO
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

I have searched the internet high and low for a solution and I haven't found one. The rest of my function looks like this:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
```

{

```
// Initialise GLFW
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    return -1;
}

glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 0); // 4x antialiasing
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //We don't want the old OpenGL

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
if( !glfwOpenWindow( 800, 600, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n" );
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}


// Initialize GLEW
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}

glfwSetWindowTitle( "Game Engine" );


// Create and bind a VAO
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );
```

Comment: Are you *intending* to use C++/CLI or C++/CX?

Comment: I'm sorry: what's this `int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)`?

Comment: It is possible that the VAO creation is failing. You're not checking for GL errors.

Comment: @Jeffery It looks like C++/CLI which is really only useful for interoperability and not writing real programs, which is why I asked if the OP intends to use it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is TBH. I've changed it from CLR to Win32 Console and now it's running through int main()..

It's still running the same error where it is getting access violation on

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

Comment: I also just added a CheckForErrors() function and it's returning a

GL_INVALID_ENUM error. (after google it says that might be a driver issue?)

Comment: Which call does throw the error exactly? Is it possible that you did not get open gl 3.3 and glGenVertexArrays is not bound? Does it throw on read or write access? What address exactly?

Comment: where did you add "CheckForErrors" and where did it report "GL_INVALID_ENUM". you can wrap every opengl call with a checkForErrors function to get the specific call that threw the error or use gDebugger. But in this case the most likely cause is that you're driver does not support opengl 3.3, thus doesn't have glGenVertexArrays. even if your graphics card supports opengl 3.3, if you're on linux or mac, driver support might be up to 2.1 only